# Identificar oraciones subordinadas

Tags: sintaxis

Tengo que analizar el tipo de oraciones subordinadas y no estoy segura de haberlas identificado correctamente (solo los fragmentos en negrita). ¿Podríais por favor echarle un vistazo?

> (1) En su momento se pondrían de acuerdo sobre el modo de formalizar
>   el compromiso **según el grado de aceptación que ella hubiera logrado
>   de su padre**.

¿oración modal?

> (2) Los idiomas hay que saberlos cuando uno va a vender algo. Pero
>   cuando uno va a comprar, todo el mundo le entiende **como sea**.

¿oración relativa?

> (3) Sabía **que ni él ni ningún otro hombre la hubiera despertado** a
>   las tres de la madrugada sólo para beber oporto y comer pan.

¿oración completiva? se usa el subjuntivo porque negamos el antecedente, ¿verdad?

> (4) Correspondía a su imagen pública: era de recursos escasos, de
>   maneras torpes, y sufría de unos sobresaltos súbitos, **ya fueran de
>   alegría o de disgusto**, y de unos rubores inoportunos que hacían
>   temer por su fortaleza mental.

Me parece una estructura concesiva pero no estoy segura.

Comment: "Según el grado de aceptación que ella hubiera logrado de su padre" no es una oración en sí sino un sintagma preposicional con función de complemento de modo. La oración subordinada es "que ella hubiera logrado de su padre", proposición adjetiva con función de complemento de nombre de "aceptación".

Comment: En (2), "como sea" no es tampoco una oración sino una locución adverbial en función de complemento de modo (ver [§22.12p](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OGfgbfzhFoQyljI,)). En (3),  se trata efectivamente de una oración completiva, pero esta comprendería desde "que" hasta el final, no solo la parte resaltada. El subjuntivo no se usa porque se niegue el antecedente, sino por una cuestión de alternancia entre subjuntivo y condicional (la *hubiera ≈ habría* despertado).

Comment: @Yay yo creo que tus comentarios dan para una respuesta la mar de maja ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui No estaba segura de que fuera on-topic, pero parece que la comunidad le ha dado el visto bueno.

Comment: @Yay la autora realizó una investigación previa, así que se puede dar por válida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Dado que no hay un verbo principal, sino solo uno subordinado ("que hubiera logrado"), no se trata de una oración sino de un sintagma preposicional en función de **complemento circunstancial de modo**. La oración es "que ella hubiera logrado de su padre", que hace de complemento de nombre de "aceptación" y es una subordinada adjetiva especificativa.

2) "Como sea" es un elemento [lexicalizado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicalizaci%C3%B3n) (o al menos semi-lexicalizado), por lo que, aunque tenga un verbo conjugado, no puede analizarse como una oración. Según la [Nueva gramática](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OGfgbfzhFoQyljI,) (§22.12p), se trata de una locución adverbial inespecífica en función de complemento de modo.

3) La oración subordinada es efectivamente una oración completiva, o subordinada sustantiva, en función de complemento directo. Sin embargo, la subordinada va desde "que" hasta el final de la frase. Esto se ve claramente si se remplaza la subordinada por "eso":

> <sup>X</sup>Sabía eso a las tres de la madrugada sólo para beber oporto y comer pan.
>
> <sup>✓</sup>Sabía eso.

La razón de que se use el subjuntivo no está relacionada con el antecedente (de hecho, no hay ninguna construcción relativa), sino que se usa porque en algunas situaciones el subjuntivo puede alternar libremente con el condicional sin cambio de significado (ver [§24.2s](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=peUXmDSvojCtodJP)):

> Sabía que ni él ni ningún otro hombre la (hubiera/habría) despertado a las tres de la madrugada sólo para beber oporto y comer pan.

4) "Ya sea(n)/ya fuera(n)" es también un elemento lexicalizado, por lo que debe entenderse como una locución conjuntiva distributiva.